# Chained macro invocations. Argument in parentheses treated differently?

Tags: c, macros

```
#define A(p1, p2, p3, p4) foo(p1, p2, p3, p4)
#define B(s) A(p1, p2, (s), p4)
```

Here, A() is a macros binding, aimed to increase portability should we ever need to call bar(p1, p2, p3, p4) and not want to rewrite the whole code base.

Now I am trying to define B() to make writing easier on me, as p1, p2 and p4 have usually the same values. This, however, does not work, unless I remove the parentheses around s. *What is going on? What am I passing to A?*

---

Turns out that:

```
#define foo(p1, p2, p3, p4) p1 ## p2 ## p3 ## p4()
```

I am not sure where p4 is defined, though, I just have a valid value. So, when I pass (s) instead of s, i get `p1p2` instead of `p1p2sp4`.

Comment: Remember that macros are expanded _as is_ in the code. It's basically copy-pasting the body of the macros into the code, with the arguments replaced with what you passed, verbatim. What a macro does depends very much on how you "call" it, so could you please show how you use it?

Comment: What does `foo` do? If it does for example toke-pasting, a parenthesis would lead to an invalid token.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, So I am passing "(" + <value of s> + ")"? Right! And then A (which actually concatinates it's inputs by simple `p1 ## p2 ## p3 ## p4`) actually stops before the third argument. Oh, I hate macros.

Comment: What _are_ you passing to A indeed? The only reason you don't get a syntax error is probably because p1, p2, p4 are some identifiers defined in the scope B is used, which is probably not what you intended to achieve. More code to put things in context would be nice.

Comment: No, there's no concatenation since you don't do any concatenation. When you do `B(something)` in your code, the preprocessor simply replaces it with `foo(p1, p2, (something), p4)`. This last code is what the compiler will see, and if `something` is not a valid expression then you will get an error, or if `foo` expects more than four arguments, or if... and so on. You need to show use some real code, and how `B` is used in your real code. And if you get compilation errors, then you need to show us them too (all of them and unedited). Otherwise we will only be able to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: you can try gcc -E source.c command to get what exactly getting pasted in place of MACRO.In this manner you could debug what is acting as wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I am passing "(" +  + ")"? Right! And then A (which actually concatinates it's inputs by simple `p1 ## p2 ## p3 ## p4`) actually stops before the third argument

Yes, then `foo` produces

```
p1 ## p2 ## ( s ) ## p4
```

and pasting the parentheses to `p4` resp. `p1 ## p2` produces invalid tokens thus the whole thing is refused.

For token-pasting, parentheses are a big no-no.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to find out what's getting passed to what is by trying it out.  You didn't say what's not working with the parentheses around `s`, so I don't know what sort of error you're expecting. The following code includes the macro defintions you provided, and uses them in a context where `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, and `p4` are variables (so that when they appear in the expansion of `B`, they have values).

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define A(p1, p2, p3, p4) foo(p1, p2, p3, p4)
#define B(s) A(p1, p2, (s), p4)

void foo( int a, int b, int c, int d ) {
  printf( "%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d );
}

int main() {
  int p1 = 101, p2 = 102, p4 = 104;

  A( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
  B( 7 );

  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles without any problems, and has sensible output.  It doesn't appear that arguments in parentheses are being treated any differently than arguments not in parentheses.

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
$ ./a.out 
1 2 3 4
101 102 7 104
```

Comment: This was posted before the OP mentioned that `foo` is another macro that concatenates its arguments.  The problem appearing there is that concatenation with parenthesis has some difficulties, but it's precisely _because_ arguments are being passed in the _same_ way (simple text substitution), and that they do _not_ get special processing.